# stored procedure returns ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION does not exist

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursors, functions

I have a stored procedure and function as below

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE ProcName()
begin
....
DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  select A.PList, B.nid from persons A inner join articles B on
 A.aid=B.id;
....
REPEAT
    FETCH curs INTO var1, var2;
    ....
    SELECT SPLITER(var1,"|",a) into @Name;
    ....
UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;
CLOSE curs;
END
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLITER(x VARCHAR(255),  delim VARCHAR(12),  pos INT) 
RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos), 
LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),delim, '')
```

now the select statement of the cursor returns about 400,000 records, and thus once i
`call ProcName` it returns *ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION myDb.SPLITER does not exist*
if i changed the query of cursor to handle 50,000 only (as limit) the procedure works fine!!
any idea of how to overcome this issue?
Thanks for your help